# Vuejs using foreach in computed property. Blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm PHP developer and have very basic knowledge of js and vuejs, sorry if it looks too stupid.
I'm building very complex reactive financial calculator. 
P.S. I work on Laravel(blade templates) and fetching data into vue using blade `@foreach()`

My problem is computed property. I need to find one value from very complex math formula (code below shows little part for the whole idea. On my computed `cashDivideds()` function I need to make some math to find value for each object in array. I use this way: `@foreach($preferredEquities as $equities)`. After all calculations I get output with right value but only for the 1st `$equity` in database.

Questions: How to `SUM` my computed values from each `$equity`.

Below my code, hope it's enough information to understand my problem.

```
new Vue({
    el: "#waterfall",
    data: {
        form: {
            exit_value: 0,
            exit_date: moment(),
            uncovered_debt: 0,
            transaction_fees: 0,
            remaining_exit: "",
        },
    },
    computed: {
        remainingExit () {
            return this.form.exit_value - this.form.uncovered_debt - this.form.transaction_fees
        },
        cashDividends() {

            @foreach($preferredEquities as $equity)
                @if($equity->dividends == false)
                    return  0
                @elseif($equity->dividends == true && $equity->dividend_type == 'equity')
                    return 0
                @elseif($equity->dividends == true && $equity->dividend_type == 'cash' && $equity->compounding == false)
                    var exit_date = this.form.exit_date;
                    var creation_date = moment("{{ $equity->creation_date }}");
                    //Date Difference: days
                    var days_difference = creation_date.diff(exit_date,'days');
                    var days_difference = Math.abs(days_difference);

                    // Accrual Frequency Percentage
                    var daily = (days_difference / 365) * {{ $equity->dividend_percent }};

                    //Total Cash Dividend
                    @if($equity->dividend_frequency == "Daily")
                        var cash_dividend = daily * ({{ $equity->share_price * $equity->shares_authorized }});
                    @endif
            @endforeach

            OUTPUT: need to return sum of cash_dividend for each $equity. Need help with this part
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

- First save your php array in a variable/array from your data/state in the mounted() hook..

  ```
  mounted() {
   this.dataToWork = {!! $preferredEquities !!}
  }
  ```
- Work with the data using only js, handling the js array.. don't complicate things using blade functions inside Vue.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the logic from the blade template and do it somewhere else maybe in the controller or some service (depending on how you build an application). Then just pass a variable with the value to the blade template. This means your template is easier to understand and less cryptic. Once in the variable is in the template you can then just dump it out as a value to the JavaScript.

Comment: I would do the same, but for calculations I must use few DOM inputs :(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You could give all the data to the frontend and then perform the logic in the frontend?